# Detecting a file update in BATCH

Tags: batch-file, cmd

CLOSED STRING DUE TO LACK OF HELPFUL COMMENTS

I am attempting to write a slew of code that registers when a file is updated, then displays the updated file. I have tried many things and nothing is working. Is there a way to check for updates to a file, and then run a command if it does, and wait for a change if it does not?

UPDATE:
I realize I am not giving as much information as I thought I was.
I am creating a batch file that will run off of a local network drive that hosts a chat room. I have created a program where you have the chat box for input and a read box for the output. I then have two log files, one for the log of user login, and another for user messages.

I need the messages screen to update all of the users when someone posts a comment. I have it set up to reload every second, but it is a little eye-hurting.

Is there any way I can tell the read file to loop back once it indicates there is a change in the messages file?

Thank you guys for the help I have been recieved.

I appreciate any help. Tell me in case I missed anything I need to add.

Comment: What defines a *file update*? A change in date/time? A modification to size? A new file being created? A file being deleted? What specific problem are you trying to solve? When asking a question here, remember that we know *absolutely nothing* about what you're trying to do, and we can't read your mind to get additional details. The only information we have is what you put in your post. Read it from our point of view (having no idea what you're trying to do).

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. Please try to write some code before asking. Visit this website to learn more: [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: looks like you are looking for the archive attribute See `attrib /?`

Comment: I apologize for the lack of information. I am attempting to detect changes to the contents of a txt file. ex: Line1 -> Line1 and Line2

Comment: SteveFest I have written code before and I will be willing to link the code. However I did not want to put more than I needed to, and I was wanting an answer that will allow me to use this code for more than just this project. I have done this before, I just hit a road block and asked for help. Apparently this is not the place to ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use one file per user to check the status. This allows you to make different ads in your own window.

The chat window does not necessarily have to be shared - but it is possible to split it.

The display does not have to be updated again and again, it is activated only for writing and otherwise it shows the messages of other users or their own settings.

Status messages are displayed via the window title.

Last but not least, the messages are read out of a shared chat file using find or more. Of course you can do that with robocopy, but if that works fast enough ...

You can extend it all so that for each sent message a control file per user is created. This in turn would allow robocopy to easily monitor such a control file (s). then show the following chat history as usual in the cli and remove the control file (s). that should at least calm the batch a bit.

I have a very old chat program (I wrote it during a training session to chat with the others, I was bored).
It uses the downloadable choice.exe, which must be placed in the same directory as the script.
Sure, I would write it today quite differently, and so it works with xcopy instead of choice (keyword SnakeBatch). But I'm too lazy. I added some comments ...

And I also admit that this script is not well written - but it's just old, special and ugly. Since this script is already lying around for a while with me in the filing - I am of opinion I operate no script writing service (may the others forgive me). Yes it goes a little bit over the question, but what is it ...

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal

 rem Vars: color text - backround 
set "LC=f"
set "BC=0"
set "Full=            "
color %BC%%LC%
set "NameSearch=%~n0"
set "NameSearch=%NameSearch:~,-1%?%~x0"
ver |find " XP " >nul && (set "UEB="
  set "XP=/c:"::x [\!One!]""
)
ver |find " XP " >nul || set "UEB=1" &&set "XP=/c:"::v [\!One!]""
:: Freigabe schon verfügbar ?
::net use
::net share
mountvol|find /i ":\">"%temp%\test"
for %%i in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
  find /i "%%i:\" "%temp%\test">nul || for /f "delims=" %%k in ('
   " for /r "%%i:\"  %%j in ("%Namesearch%") do if "%~nx0" == "%%~nxj" echo "%%j" "
  ') do set "LWShare=%%~dpk"
)

 rem status file switch
:: Nur eine Datei davon maximal Vorhanden
:: --------------------------------------
:: Batch Chat User Angemeldet   ".bca"
:: Batch Chat User Schreibt ".bcw"
:: Batch Chat User Offline  ".bco"  rem NOT in use: list old/unused names
:: Batch Chat User Idle     ".bci"
:: 

 rem status file beep
:: Batch Chat User Ring     ".bcr"

 rem NOT in use: only test  file switch - private , timer
:::: nach der Anmeldung immer Vorhanden
:::: --------------------------------------
:::: Batch Chat User Timer  ".bct"
:::: Batch Chat User Privat ".bcp"

 rem color code
:: code Farbe       Bedeutung              Schrift H-grund
::  0   Schwarz     Andere Anwesend             x
::  8   D-Grau      Allein Anwesend             x
::  1   D-Blau      Anderer Benutzer schreibt       x
::  7   H-Grau      Option Aus          x
::  f   Weis        Option Ein/Eingabe Fertig   x
::  c   Rot     Erkennung eines Befehles    x
::  a   Grün        Benutzer schreibt       x
::  b   Zyan        <Benutzer : Meldung>        x
::  d   Magenta     Modus Idle          x
::  e   Gelb        Nachricht Erhalten      x
::  2   D-Grün
::  3   BlauGrün
::  4   D-Rot
::  5   Lila
::  6   Ocker
::  9   Blau




::goto :begin
:settings

 rem idle  message - file = .bci
 rem write message - file = .bcw
 rem self - idle  info message
 rem self - write info message
 rem self - alone info message
set     "IdleInfo=... liegt grad sinnlos herum"
set    "WriteInfo=... schreibt gerade"
set   "MyIdleInfo=... Ich mach grad eine 15"
set  "MyWriteInfo=: Ich Schreibe gerade etwas ..."
set    "AloneInfo=Du bist am Arsch der Welt"

:begin
if defined LWShare ( pushD "%LWShare%" ) else pushD "%~dp0"

 rem Input variant  choice.exe
if not exist "%temp%\choice.exe" copy /y /z choice.exe "%temp%\choice.exe" >nul||(echo Keine choice.exe im Verzeichnis vorhanden&pause&goto :eof)
title Chat for CMD-Line
echo Chat Server Laufwerk: "%cd%"

@echo off
set "Userin=%Username%"
echo\%Username%>"%temp%\test"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=. " %%i in ('" echo User 0& Dir /b /od "User *.bc?" 2>nul "') do (
  for /f %%j in ('" set /a x=%%~ni + 1 "') do if not exist "User %%~j.*bc?" set "Userin=User %%j"
)
Dir /b "%username%.bc?" >nul 2>&1 && ( echo Sorry "%username%" Dein Name ist schon vergeben!
) 

goto :Userin

 rem NOT in use: method usernames -  list old/unused names
:User
(for /f "delims=." %%i in ('" dir /b *.bco 2>nul && echo ---  M”gliche Benutzernamen "') do echo %%i
)>"%temp%\file"
sort "%temp%\file"

:Userin
 rem - list used usernames
(for /f "delims=." %%i in ('" dir /b *.bc? 2>nul |findstr /r /c:"[awi]$" && echo ---  Belegte Benutzernamen "') do echo %%i
)>"%temp%\file"
sort "%temp%\file"
set "USER="


:Userin
 rem username
set /p User="Waehle einen anderen Benutzernamen oder mit nur Enter waehle "%Userin%" "
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if not defined User set "User=%username%"
echo\!User!>"%temp%\test"
endlocal
findstr /v /r "[?.</>\\|:;%%=~*\[\]()&]" "%temp%\test"|findstr /v /r /c:"[ ]$"|findstr /v /r "^-" >nul || (cls & echo Nicht Verwertbare Zeichen gefunden!& goto :User )
if defined User findstr "[0-Z][0-Z][0-Z]" "%temp%\test" || echo Zu wenig Zeichen! Anderen Namen waehlen!&& Goto :User
if defined User Dir /b "%user%.bc?" "%user%.*.bc?" >nul 2>&1 && echo Benutzername "%User%" ist schon vergeben - anderen Namen waehlen!&& goto :User

if not defined User for /f "tokens=2 delims=. " %%i in ('" echo User 0& Dir /b /od "User *.bc?" 2>nul "') do if not defined User for /f %%j in ('" set /a x=%%~ni + 1 "') do if not exist "User %%~j.*bc?" set "User=User %%j"

@echo off
cls
for /f %%i in (' cmd /u /von /c"echo !user!"^|find /v ""^|findstr .^|find /c /v "" ') do call set "Free=%%Full:~%%i%%" 
if not defined Free set "Free= "
if not exist Chat.log type nul > Chat.log
set "Spot=Echo\^<%User% : spot Befehl Erkennung^>"
set "Echo=1"

:ReFresh
set "LC=f"
set "BC=0"
color %BC%%LC%
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo Hallo !user!   ... Willkommen im Chat
for /f %%i in ('" Dir /b *.bc? 2>nul|findstr /v /r /c:"[.]bco$"|findstr /v /r /c:"^%User%[.]"|find /v /c "" 2>nul "') do if %%i equ 0 (echo Du bist der erste Hier! & if not defined Gr1 if exist Chat.log del Chat.log & type nul > Chat.log ) else echo Es sind bereits %%i Personen im Chat.&echo\&(for /f "delims=." %%i in ('" Dir /b /od *.bc? 2>nul|findstr /v /r /c:"^%User%[.]*bc"|findstr /r /c:"[.]bc[aiw]$" "') do echo %%~i)& echo und Du : !USER!
echo\&echo  Zum Abmelden    EXIT    eingeben oder 0 Drcken
echo    Fuer Hilfe  HELP    eingeben oder 1 Drcken
echo .......................................................................&echo\
type nul > "!User!.bca"
endlocal
if not defined Gr1 for %%i in (Chat.log) do set /a Gr = %%~zi , Gr1 = %%~zi
if not defined LL1 for /f %%i in ('" find /v /c "" < "Chat.log" 2>nul "') do set /a lastline = %%i , LL1 = %%i

::echo Vorher : %LL1% Nachher : %Lastline% Letztes Löschen: %LastClear% Naechstes Löschen : %OldClear%
if "%one%" == "ref" set /a Gr = Gr1 , lastline = LL1  & (if defined Lastclear set /a lastline=LastClear)&set "one="& goto :Anfang
::  echo on
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(
echo ^<!User! : Hat den Chat betreten ...^>
)>> Chat.log
endlocal

:Anfang
@echo off
if not defined Users (
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('" Dir /b /od *.bc? 2>nul | findstr /v /r /c:"[.]bc[wo]$" | findstr /v /r /c:"^%User%[.]" || Dir /b /od *.bcw >nul 2>nul || title Hallo "%USER%" %Info% %AloneInfo% "') do call set "Users=%%Users%%:%%~ni"
) && set "BC=0" || set "BC=8"

if not defined Write (
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('" dir /b /od *.bcw 2>nul "') do call set "Write=%%Write%%:%%~ni"
)

if not defined Wrote (
set "Wrote=1" & for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ("%Write%") do  set "Write=%%j" & Dir "%%~i.bcw" >nul 2>nul && title "%User%" %Info% Chat "%%i"
) else  set "Wrote=" & for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%i in ("%Users%") do set "Users=%%j" & Dir "%%~i.bca" "%%~i.bci" >nul 2>&1 && title "%User%" %Info% Chat mit "%%i"

if exist *.bcw set "BC=1"
color %BC%%LC%
for %%h in ("%user%.*bcr") do for /f "usebackq delims=" %%i in ("%%~h") do del "%user%.*bcr"&echo ^<%%i: macht L„rm - Ring Ring Ring Ring Ring ... ^>&set "Ring=2")
if defined Ring <nul set /p "="&if "%ring%" == "0" (set "Ring=") else set /a Ring - = 1
for %%i in (Chat.log) do if "%%~zi" neq "%Gr%" (set /a Gr = %%~zi ) else goto :Write
if defined mIn set mIn=^|findstr /v /r /c:"^%user%[ ]*: " 2^>nul
for /f %%i in ('" find /v /c "" < "Chat.log" 2>nul "') do (
  if %%i neq %lastline% ( set "LC=f"
    if %%i lss %lastline% more +%LastClear% Chat.log| find /v ""
      if %%i gtr %lastline% more +%lastline% Chat.log%mIn% | find /v "" && set "LC=e" && if defined one (
        if defined Auto more +%lastline% Chat.log%mIn% |findstr /v /r /c:"^<.*>$" >nul 2>nul&& echo ^<%user%    : Auto Message!! %time:~0,-3% : Bin net da!^>>>Chat.log&&(%Beep%
          rem beep for incoming Message
      )|| set "LC=b"
      if not defined Auto more +%lastline% Chat.log%mIn% |findstr /v /r /c:"^<.*>$" >nul 2>nul&& (%Beep%
        set "LC=e"
      )|| set "LC=b"
    )
    set /a lastline = %%i
  )
)

color %BC%%LC%
:Write
if defined Echo (
  %BeepM%
  %AutoM%
  %Spot%
   rem Optionen Anzeigen
)
set "Echo="
set "mIn="
%Message%
set "Message="
set "one="
@echo off
(
for /f "eol=" %%i in ('" %temp%\choice /cabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!$%%.,\`\`\"\"{}()?/\[]*#-+^=:;_'^^^&õ§@~ /n /s /t,1 "') do for /f "eol= delims=" %%j in ("%%i") do set "One=%%j"
) >nul

if not exist "%user%.bco" if exist "%User%.*bc?" ( if defined One call :WriteIn ) else goto :eof
if /i "%One%" == "ref" %bp%cls&goto :ReFresh
set "one="

if exist "*.bca" goto :Anfang
if exist "*.bcw" goto :Anfang
if exist "*.bci" goto :Anfang
set "LC=f"
set "BC=0"
color %BC%%LC%
goto :EOF

:WriteIN
::@echo off

set "Info="
set "LC=c"
if exist *.bcw set "BC=1"
title Chat von "%User%"  : Eingabe erkannt
color %BC%%LC%

::@echo off
set "OneX="
set "oney="

:Check
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
@echo off
if exist *.bcw set "BC=1"
color %BC%%LC%

::: Ersetze in v+7: z mit y + Tabelle
set "New="
set "OneX="
if not defined UEB goto :noUEB
if not defined one goto :noUEB
if !one! geq 0 if !one! leq x goto :noUEB
for /f "eol= tokens=2,3" %%i in ('findstr /b /r %XP% "%~f0"') do if not defined OneX if "%%i" == "!One!" set "OneX=%%j"&set "One="
:noUEB
set "One=!oney!!OneX!!One!"
set "OneX="&set "oney="
@echo off
for %%i in (
 "1 help hel he h"
 "2 cls cl c"
 "3 ref re r"
 "4 load loa lo l"
 "5 idle idl id i"
 "6 auto aut au a"
 "7 beep bee be b"
 "8 spot spo sp s"
 "9 ring rin ri"
 "0 exit exi ex e" ) do for /f "tokens=1,2*" %%j in ("%%~i") do (
  if /i "%%j" == "!One!" ( set "One=" & set "New=%%k"
  ) else if defined Spot if /i "%%~k" == "!one!" ( set "New=!One!" && set "One="
  ) else for %%m in (%%~l) do if /i "%%m" == "!One!" set "OneX=!One!" && set "One="
)

if not defined OneX goto :NoCheck
title Chat von "%User%"  : Eingabe Auto - Erkennung :  ^<!OneX!^>
for /f "eol=" %%i in ("!OneX!") do endlocal & set "oney=%%i" & set "One="

 rem input Variant
(
for /f "eol=" %%i in ('
 " %temp%\choice /cabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ!$%%.,\`\`\"\"{}()?/\[]*#-+^=:;_'^^^&õ§@~ /n /s /t,1 "
 ') do for /f "eol= delims=" %%j in ("%%i") do set "One=%%j"
) >nul
goto :Check

:NoCheck
@echo off
if defined New goto :Idle
color %BC%a
for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do ren "%%~i" "%User%.%WriteInfo%.bcw"
title Chat von "%User%" %MyWriteInfo%
set /p New=!User!%Free%: !One!

:Idle
set "LC=f"
if /i !one!!new! == IDLE for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do ren "%%~i" "!User!.!IdleInfo!.bci"& Echo\^<!User!    : !one!!New!^>& endlocal & set "Info=%MyIdleInfo%" & set "LC=d" & goto :eof

if /i not !one!!New! == RING goto :NoRing
for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do ren "%%~i" "!User!.bci"
for /f "delims=." %%i in ('" dir /b *.bc? 2>nul |findstr /r /c:"[awi]$" "') do echo\!user! >"%%i.bcr"
endlocal&set "LC=f"
goto :eof

:NoRing
if /i not !one!!new! == CLS goto :NoCls
for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do ren "%%~i" "%User%.bca"
cls
echo\^<!User!   : Anzeige geleert^>
%BeepM%
%AutoM%
endlocal & set "LC=f" & set /a LastClear=lastline , OldClear=lastline & set "one=ref" & set "Echo=1" & goto :eof

:NoCls
if /i !one!!new! == BEEP for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do ren "%%~i" "%User%.bca"& if defined Beep ( Echo\^<!User! : !one!!New! - AUS^>& endlocal & set "BeepM=" & set "Beep=" & set "LC=7" & goto :eof) else Echo\^<!User! : !one!!New!^>& endlocal & set "BeepM=Echo\^<%User%    : %one%%New%^>"& set "Beep=<nul set /p =" & set "LC=f" & goto :eof

if /i !one!!new! == AUTO for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do ren "%%~i" "%User%.bca"& if defined Auto ( Echo\^<!User! : !one!!New! Nachricht - AUS^>&endlocal&set "Auto="&set "AutoM="&set "LC=7"&goto :eof) else Echo\^<!User! : !one!!New! Nachricht^>& endlocal & set "Auto=1" & set "AutoM=Echo\^<%User%  : %one%%New% Nachricht^>" & set "LC=f" & goto :eof

if /i not !one!!new! == HELP goto :NoHelp

 rem Help message
set "LC=f"
set "BC=0"
color %BC%%LC%
for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do ren "%%~i" "!User!.bca"
title CMD Chatprogramm Hilfe
cls
findstr /b /c:"::: " "%~f0"
ping localhost -n 6 >nul & endlocal & set "One=ref" & set "Echo=1" & goto :eof
:NoHelp

:Exit
if /i !one!!new! == EXIT (for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do findstr . "%%~i" >nul || del "%%~i" >nul
echo ^<!User! Hat den Chat verlassen ...^>
)>> Chat.log & goto :eof

:Ref
if /i !one!!new! == REF for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do ren "%%~i" "%User%.bca"&title Chat for CMD-Line&endlocal&set "One=ref"&set "LastClear=%OldClear%"&set "Echo=1"&goto :eof

:Load
if /i !one!!new! == LOAD for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do ren "%%~i" "%User%.bca"&title Chat for CMD-Line&endlocal&set "One=ref"&set "OldClear=%LastClear%"&&set "LastClear="&set "Echo=1"&goto :eof

:Spot
if /i not !one!!new! == SPOT goto :NoSpot
for %%i in ("%User%.*bc?") do ren "%%~i" "%User%.bca"
title Chat for CMD-Line
endlocal
set "One="
if defined Spot (set "Spot="&Echo\^<%User% : spot Befehl Erkennung - AUS^>&set "LC=7") else set "Spot=Echo\^<%User% : spot Befehl Erkennung^>"&set "LC=f"
%Spot%
goto :eof

:NoSpot
set "New=!One!!New!"

if "!New:~0,-2!" == "" ren "%User%.%WriteInfo%.bcw" "%User%.bca"&title Chat for CMD-Line&endlocal&set "One=ref"&set "Message=echo ^<%user%  : Nachricht zu kurz - Nichts gesendet ^>"&goto :eof
if not !New! equ !Old! (
echo !USER!%free%: !New!
)>> Chat.log else set "Message=echo ^<%user%    : Kein Spam erlaubt - Nichts gesendet ^>"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ("!New!") do (endlocal
    set "Old=%%i"
  set "mIn=1"
    set "Message=%Message%"
) || ( endlocal & set "Old=" & set "Message=%Message%")
if defined Message (set "one=ref") else set "One="
ren "%User%.%WriteInfo%.bcw" "%User%.bca"
title Chat for CMD-Line
set "LC=f"
goto :eof

:::  Eingabe  oder NR       Das wird gemacht!         
:::   help  1   diese Hilfe des CMD-Chatprogamm
:::   cls   2   Bilschirm leeren
:::   ref   3   Bildschirm neu laden (ab cls)
:::   load  4   Chatverlauf von Anfang laden
:::   idle  5   Status auf besch„ftigt setzen
:::   auto  6   Automatische Antwort           Ein/Aus
:::   beep  7   Empfangston                    Ein/Aus
:::   spot  8   Befehlerkennung ohne Enter     Ein/Aus
:::   ring  9   Alle Anpiepen
:::   exit  0   Chat Verlassen
:::   
:::  Zeichen welche im Chat Auf Beginn der Tastatureingabe Reagieren
:::  
:::   ø   !   "   õ   $   %   &       (   )   =   ? 
:::   @   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   á 
:::         Q   W   E   R   T   Z   U   I   O   P   š   * 
:::         q   w   e   r   t   z   u   i   o   p      + 
:::          A   S   D   F   G   H   J   K   L   ™       ' 
:::          a   s   d   f   g   h   j   k   l   ”   „   # 
:::            Y   X   C   V   B   N   M           _ 
:::            y   x   c   v   b   n   m   ,   .   - 
::::   Achtung : das ø Grad-Zeichen wird zum @ At-Zeichen

::  Ersetzungstabelle x=xp, v=7
:: CMD  Tast    7 OUT   XP
:: -----------|--------|---
:: ^    ^   `   ^   nicht empfohlen
:: ø    °   ~   ^
:: "    "   @   "
:: õ    §   #   X
:: $    $   $   X
:: %    %   %   X
:: &    &   ^   &
:: /    /   &   X
:: (    (   *   X
:: )    )   (   X
:: =    =   )   X
:: á    ß   -   X
:: ´    ´   =   X
:: ?    ?   _   X
::  ü   [   X
:: +    +   ]   X
:: ”    ö   ;   X
:: „    ä   '   X
:: #    #   \   X
:: ,    ,   ,   X
:: .    .   .   X
:: š    Ü   {       
:: *    *   }   
:: -    -   /   
:: ™    Ö   :   
:: Ž    Ä   "   
:: _    _   ?   
:: >    >   \   


::v ~ ø
:::x ^ @
::v @ "
::v # õ
::v ^ &
::v * (
::v ( )
::v ) =
::v _ ?
::v - á
::v & /
::v ] +
::v } *
::v : ™
::v ; ”
::v " Ž
::v ' „
::v \ #
::v { š
::v [ 
::v / -
::v ? _
::v z y
::v Z Y
::v y z
::v Y Z
```